# Cannot register

Tags: support, openid

I have tried 2 different OpenID accounts to try to register and in each case I get an error and cannot register

I have cut and pasted the links suggested by both my openID accounts into the URL box on the registration page and nothing works

Answer (score 4):

If you have a dot in your user name, such as first.last.myopenid.com, you can't use the normal link to register; you will need to click the link to manually enter your ID, then enter it manually at the openid site.

I have this problem, and found the answer somewhere on the stackoverflow site.

For more information, see this discussion:  [stackoverflow openID problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71584/login-via-myopenid-does-not-work/96080#96080)